# Async Jquery com CDN

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Isn't there a way to sync (async) jQuery from Google CDN? Using it as in my example doesn't work, myscript.js is full of commands in jQuery and gives errors, what am I doing wrong? I also tested using async = "async".

```
<script async src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script async src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
<script defer src = "assets2 / js / MISCRIPT.js"> </script>
```

Comment: ...and gives errors...   Can you add errors or MISCRIPT.js?  Thanks

Comment: "$ is not defined" in myscript.js,  but everything works perfectly fine without using it